# emacs: how to indent/unindent region of python code by 4 spaces?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, python, text-editing, indentation

I have a region of python code selected in emacs. What are the most efficient ways to indent and unindent every line in it by 4 spaces?

Ideally I'd like something that's not context sensitive (eg. it'll allow me to indent passages within docstrings where the indentation does not relate to python syntax).

My mode line shows `(Python)`. Searching the web I found a lot of discussion of using [`python-mode`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-mode/) instead of `python`, but I only started using emacs a few days ago so I'm wary of changing defaults before I have had a chance to understand and them. If changing to `python-mode` is the best option I'm happy to accept that as an answer.

What I've tried (from the manual):

- `<TAB>` no effect
- `C-M-\` no effect
- `C-x <TAB>` (indent-rigidly) indent every line by one column (and deselects the region)
- `M-i` indents one first line by a tab (length of 8 spaces)
- `C-M-q` - "C-M-q is undefined"

The only way I've found is using regex-replace, but that's an awful number of keystrokes for such a simple task.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Assuming that the variable `python-indent` is 4:

```
M-x python-shift-right (C-c >)
M-x python-shift-left  (C-c <)
```

Comment: I had to do `python-indent-shift-left`.

Answer (score 18):

`indent-rigidly` takes a prefix argument indicating how much to indent by, so `C-u 42 C-x TAB` indents by 42 columns, and since the default prefix argument is 4, `C-u C-x TAB` indents by 4 columns.

If you want to select the region again, do `C-x C-x` afterwards.

Answer (score 10):

Use the indent-rigidly command with a numeric prefix.

`C-u 4 M-x indent-rigidly` to indent the region by four spaces, `C-u -4 M-x indent-rigidly` to remove four spaces.

Answer (score 4):

C-x C-x 
mark the code and then 
M-x indent-for-tab-mode

That's the save if you have pressed tab for every line.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use column mode.

Select the lines in column mode, then add four spaces to all of them at once:

1. Jump to column 1 of the first line you want to indent.
2. `C-<space>` to set mark
3. move the point down to the last lines (stay in column one)
4. `C-x r t` to enter column mode (or `C-<RET>` if you've got CUA mode)
5. `<space><space><space><space><RET>`

You can do a similar maneuver to delete four spaces -- just include 4 columns in your marked region (steps 2-3) and hit `<DEL>`

Answer (score 3):

Updating Chen's solution above, currently (tested on Emacs 24.4.1) the commands have been renamed. So, assuming you want to indent according to the variable python-indent, the commands are python-indent-shift-left and python-indent-shift-right. You can:

1. issue them by typing `M-x python-indent-shift-right` or `M-x python-indent-shift-left`
2. use the default python-mode short cuts `C-c >` and `C-c <`
3. rebind them. E.g., on a keyboard with a windows button I use:

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "s-s") 'python-indent-shift-left) 
   (global-set-key (kbd "s-d") 'python-indent-shift-right)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Composability is the king with Emacs, just combine `M-i` with https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el and you have your indent block command. That is you do:

1. `M->` N times (where N is the number of lines in block)
2. `M-i`

Answer (score 0):

Both [`S-<LEFT>` and `S-<RIGHT>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html) work fine in `Python` major mode. It is especially convenient in [Cua Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) where `C-c` and `C-x` behavior changes to copy/cut when a region is selected.